# FMOD Voice Chat

Tags: network-programming, fmod, voice-recording

I want to create a voice chat software using FMOD.
Now I can receive data from microphone and play it immediately.
It's also easy to send sound data to another computer on the network.
But I don't know how to play the sent data on the other computer with FMOD.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the incoming sound data on the destination machine you need to create a streaming buffer to play the audio. The simplest method would be to look at the userccreatedsound example. It shows how to create a custom stream buffer and use the pcmreadcallback to populate the sound with data as needed.